# Draw a fill rectangle dynamically on screen in C#

Tags: c#, screen, draw

I would like to draw a fill rectangle dynamically on my screen, with an opacity at 0.1. The problem is that when i move the mouse, the previous rectangles aren't clear.

This is the drawing methods.

```
    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;

        g = this.selectorForm.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isMouseDown) return;

        this.selectorForm.Invalidate();
        g.FillRectangle(brush, this.getRectangle(x, y, e.X, e.Y));
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, this.getRectangle(x, y, e.X, e.Y));

    }
```

This is my selectorForm

```
    internal class SelectorForm : Form
    {
        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

[An example when I draw a rectangle (several overlapping rectangles)](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/07/1423906320-selector.png)

And `Invalidate()` doesn't work because I override `OnPaintBackground`. But if I don't do this override, when I do `this.selectorForm.Show()`, [my screen becomes gray](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/07/1423906070-white.png).

So how can I draw a rectangle with an opacity 0.1 on my screen?

Thank you !

Comment: Instead of Invalidate, you tried Refresh?

Comment: have you tried inserting a g.Clear ?

Comment: I don't understand your setup. How many forms are involved?  On which control or form are the OnMouseDown/Move events?? Why use a bool when you can simply check the e.Button? Why draw in the move instead of the Paint??? The last point is always a mistake: you can pass Graphics around __from__ the Paint event but not if you create them in code and still expect it to keep the screen updated!

Comment: I tried Refresh and Update but my override OnPaintBackground seems "break" them too.
TaW, i use one Form (selectorForm) who is created by a "Window" class. Ok for the bool and e.Button. And i don't understand your last sentence sorry (i'm french and my english isn't very good...)

Comment: OK, there is a standard way to draw onto a Control in GDI+ and this is by using the Paint event (or OnPaint). Here the Graphics object is provided in the Parameter e and should always be used. (There are a few exceptions but the rule is: Do it in the Paint event!) - My answer shows you an example..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example that works for me.

The crucial parts are:

- using the `Paint` event and **its** `Graphics`
- adding a `Clear(BackgroundColor)` or else I get the same artifacts you see
- for transparency the TransparencyKey property should be used. There is a certain choice of colors:

  - Common colors may conflict with other things on the Form
  - Fuchsia works **if** you want to **click through** the Form
  - Other not so common colors are suitable; I chose a light green

You may want to adapt to your way of setting up events, I just did it this way for faster testing.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Opacity = 0.1f;
        // a color that will allow using the mouse on the form:
        BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        TransparencyKey = BackColor;
    }

    Point mDown = Point.Empty;
    Point mCur = Point.Empty;

    private void Form2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = e.Location;
    }

    private void Form2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = Point.Empty;
    }

    private void Form2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        mCur = e.Location;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       if (mDown == Point.Empty) return;
       Size s = new System.Drawing.Size(Math.Abs(mDown.X - mCur.X),
                                        Math.Abs(mDown.Y - mCur.Y)  );
       Point topLeft = new Point(Math.Min(mDown.X, mCur.X), 
                                 Math.Min(mDown.Y, mCur.Y));
       Rectangle r = new Rectangle(topLeft, s);
       e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);                // <--- necessary!
       e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Bisque, r );   // <--- pick your..
       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r);         // <--- colors!
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I just tried this and i understand for the Paint method, thank you. But i realize that you use a Form with a background color.
My objective is to draw an area on my screen for take a screenshot, so i need to draw when i am on my browser, when i am on my desktop, etc. And this area is represented by a fill rectangle and an opacity of 0.1 for it.
So i can't use a form with a background (and i can't use e.Graphics.Clear(Color color)). My form needs to be transparent. And I can not. :\

Comment: You are mistaken about the Background color of your form, as I have pointed out above. If you want the Form to be tranparent you should use TransparencyKey as I have just added to my answer!

Comment: Nice, it works as i wanted ! =D
But when i move the mouse, the rectangle twinkles. Is this normal ?
Example here : http://youtu.be/N7w_5fJbtyw

Comment: Have you incuded `DoubleBuffered = true;` ?

Comment: No... It's done and now it works very well. Thank you so much! My account is too new to vote but the solution is here! ^^

Comment: You can't vote, but you can accept then answer by clicking on the checkmark you find under the voting arrows at the top left of the answer..

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
    g.Clear();
    g.FillRectangle(brush, this.getRectangle(x, y, e.X, e.Y));
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, this.getRectangle(x, y, e.X, e.Y));
```

Comment: I've ever tried but Clear need a Color parameter. And when i tried with Color.Transparent, my screen becomes black.

Comment: What color do you use for the form's background color? that's what should be used imo.

Comment: My form hasn't a background color, i can draw on but it is'nt visible. In fact, I would like to draw a rectangle on my screen (browser, desktop, etc) so i can't use a color background. I want take a region screenshot.

Thanks Yuri Dorokhov, i try.

Comment: _My form hasn't a background color_ Yes it has. You can't have a Form without a BackgroundColor. Look at it in the Designer! Try to delete the BackgroundColor! See?