# How do I resize a dynamically created text box by dragging with mouse like in paint programs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a text box, inside a PictureBox, on mouse click at run time. Now I want to resize it using mouse drag. Is there some simple way to do this ?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static TextBox PTB; //declaring text box to be created
        public static bool textOption; //stores the state of button , i.e whether or not text box button is clicked before or not
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textOption == true)//if user selected option to draw text box
            {
                MouseEventArgs eM = (MouseEventArgs)e; //create an instance of mouse event
                PTB = new TextBox();//dynamically creating text box
                PTB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(eM.X, eM.Y);//settign position of textbox where mouse was clicked
                PTB.Name = "textBox1";
                PTB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);//size of text box

                this.pictureBox1.Controls.Add(PTB);//adding the textbox to the picture box
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you add tags to the platform? I guess its winforms

Comment: I'm afraid I completely misread yor question. I have added hints to what you probably want. _Is there some simple way to do this ?_ Not really simple, I'm afraid. By far the simplest way is to give up the mouse and use external controls like numUpDown or trackBars..

Answer (score 3):

The ability to resize a window is innate behavior, provided by the default window procedure built into Windows.  All you have to do is give the control a resizable border.  Everything else is for free, you'll get the correct cursor and dragging a corner or edge resizes the control.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ResizeableTextBox : TextBox {
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x840000;  // Turn on WS_BORDER + WS_THICKFRAME
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I'm sorry I have totally misread your question.

The reason is probably that you seem to be under the impression that Paint programs have TextBoxes sitting on their canvas. They don't. They draw text the same way as they draw lines or circles etc..

Also: Resizing the TextBox will not change the Font size, in case that's is what you want.

Finally: A TextBox will never be transparent, it will always sit on the PictureBox and look, well, like a TextBox. Not like anything in a Paint programm..

But: If you actually do want to resize the TextBox here are a few hints:

- You need some way to show the user they are on the right spot by changing the cursor to the right icon
- You need to store the mouse down point (attention: it will be inside the TextBox!) and keep track of the increments in the MouseMove. As long as the Button is down all rported e.Location will still be in the TextBox coordinates.
- Use the increments (not the absolute values) to increase the size of the TextBox.
- It is **really hard** to get the resizing right on the top and left sides. (Because it will involve moving at the same time), so better don't try!
- Do include moving, which is easy and will suffice for all you need.

No, this is a good deal harder than increasing font size. 200-300 lines of code, the last time I did it..

But you may find another somewhat simpler answer; look for "Resize Control with Mouse winforms c#" on [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=c%23+Resize+Control+with+Mouse&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=uQ1yVaWtCYWxUaHBgPAO#safe=off&q=Resize+Control+with+Mouse+winforms+c%23)..

I leave the old answer in place, even if it not what you were looking for..

---

**Old answer about changing font size while placing text:**

It is not very hard but you need to get it right; it is basically the same as [drawing a Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514254/draw-a-fill-rectangle-dynamically-on-screen-in-c-sharp/28515659?s=5|1.4772#28515659)
 with a live preview. You need these things: four events, a Point or two, a Size and a font variable..

The events are:

- `MouseDown`
- `MouseMove`
- `MouseUp`
- `Paint`

You need to store a point for the placement (in the `MouseDown` event) and a size you update in the `MouseMove`.

From that size you can calculate the maximum Font size you can fit in the Rectangle.

On `MouseUp` you finalize things.

In the `Paint` event you draw string at the down Point with the current Font size.

In the `MouseMove` you call `Invalidate` on the PictureBox to trigger the `Paint` event.

in the `MouseMouve` you should check the `Button` to be the left one.

For extra good UI you can also check the keyboard for `space` and use it to move the DownPoint..

The `Click` event is rather useless, btw..

Here is a minimal code example to get you started:

```
Point mDown = Point.Empty;
float fSize = 12f;

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font font = new Font("Consolas", fSize))
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", font, Brushes.Black, mDown);

}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = e.Location;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    fSize = Math.Abs(e.Y - mDown.Y) / 2f + 1;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

I left out the `MouseUp`. Here you would store the final state (font, location..) of the drawn string somewhere or persist it by drawing into a `Bitmap` etc..

I also didn't do a full Rectangle calculation but determined the font size by simply scaling the y-movement down a little.. You could improve with a little pythagoras ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This sample will create the `TextBox` on the `MouseDown` event and start resizing, the final size of the `TextBox` will be where the mouse button is released on the `MouseUp` event. It will let you create multiple textboxes as well.

I realize this might not be exactly what you want but it might be a start.

```
private int _textBoxCounter;
private TextBox _textBoxCurrentResizing;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.MouseDown += PictureBox1OnMouseDown;
    pictureBox1.MouseUp += PictureBox1OnMouseUp;
    pictureBox1.MouseMove += PictureBox1OnMouseMove;
}

public Point RelativeMousePosition { get { return PointToClient(MousePosition); } }

private void PictureBox1OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
    ResizeTextBox();
}

private void PictureBox1OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
    EndResizeTextBox();
}

private void PictureBox1OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
    var tb = CreateTextBox();
    StartResizeTextBox(tb);
}

private TextBox CreateTextBox()
{
    var tb = new TextBox
    {
        Location = RelativeMousePosition,
        Size = new Size(100, 20),
        Multiline = true,
        Name = "textBox" + _textBoxCounter++,
    };
    pictureBox1.Controls.Add(tb);
    return tb;
}

private void StartResizeTextBox(TextBox tb)
{
    _textBoxCurrentResizing = tb;
}

private void ResizeTextBox()
{
    if (_textBoxCurrentResizing == null) return;
    var width = Math.Abs(_textBoxCurrentResizing.Left - RelativeMousePosition.X);
    var height = Math.Abs(_textBoxCurrentResizing.Top - RelativeMousePosition.Y);
    _textBoxCurrentResizing.Size = new Size(width, height);
}

private void EndResizeTextBox()
{
    _textBoxCurrentResizing = null;
}
```